# ASP.NET Localize

Tags: asp.net

A simple question. I have a site with localization (with .resx files) and when i need to insert localized text i use a code like this:

```
<asp:Localize Text="<%$ Resources: MyResource, Default_BannerHomeTitle %>" runat="server">SOME_TEXT_HERE_OR_NOT?</asp:Localize>
```

The question is if anyone knows what's the utility of the text between the asp:Localize tag -> "SOME_TEXT_HERE_OR_NOT?"

The real value come from the .resx file and the text "SOME_TEXT_HERE_OR_NOT?" is obviusly deleted when the page is rendered.

Is this text used in some situation? or is never used?

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Text` property you are setting inline and the text you type between the tags is effectively the same thing. You should be using one or the other, there's no point in setting both.

The `Localize` control is just a subclass of the `Literal` control. Technically, the text you type between the tags is interpreted as its own separate `Literal` control, a "parsed sub-object". When the `Localize` control is created, its `Text` property is set to the value of the sub-object's `Text` property. However, setting the `Text` property explicitly on the `Localize` control will take precedence over anything typed between the tags.